# Silent Signin using Office365 SDK in iOS app

Tags: ios, office365

I am working on an iOS app in which the credentials of Office365 account for a user is already stored. When user click on login button the user should directly login using the credentials and not popup the web UI for
entering the credentials.

I have successfully integrated office365 SDK in the app and i am able to login by entering the credentials in the web UI. But i want to by pass the authentication screen.

Is silent login possible using the office365 iOS SDK?

Answer (score 0):

This is limited by the OAuth 2.0. ***Instead of using the resource owner's credentials to access protected resources, the client obtains an access token -- a string denoting a specific scope, lifetime, and other access attributes.*** The OAuth 2.0 address the issues when resource owner used their credentials to access protected resources:

o  *Third-party applications are required to store the resource
owner's credentials for future use, typically a password in
clear-text.*

o  *Servers are required to support password authentication, despite
the security weaknesses inherent in passwords.*

o  *Third-party applications gain overly broad access to the resource
owner's protected resources, leaving resource owners without any
ability to restrict duration or access to a limited subset of
resources.*

o  *Resource owners cannot revoke access to an individual third party
without revoking access to all third parties, and must do so by
changing the third party's password.*

o  *Compromise of any third-party application results in compromise of
the end-user's password and all of the data protected by that
password.*

However, ***the resource owner password credentials (i.e., username and password) can be used directly as an authorization grant to obtain an access token.
The credentials should only be used when there is a high degree of trust between the resource owner and the client (e.g., the client is part of the device operating system or a highly privileged application), and when other authorization grant types are not available (such as an authorization code).***

Azure AD is a public cloud identity service, the app registered on the Azure AD is not the “highly privileged application”. So I’m afraid the app cannot get the access token use the user name and password directly.

You can refer to the OAuth 2.0 Authorization Framework from link below:
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#page-4